# PHP DateTime Object convert from format A to format B

Tags: php, datetime

I have the string `'19720505'` (year + month with leading zero + day with leading zero).
How to convert it to the format `Y-m-d 00:00:00` using the PHP DateTime class?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Comment: can you use <?php
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('j-M-Y', '15-Feb-2009');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
?> without using 'New DateTime();' ?

Comment: `DateTime::createFromFormat(...)->format(...)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First convert your `yyyymmdd` to a DateTime object:

```
$inputString = "19720505";

$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("Ymd", $inputString);
```

Then convert your DateTime object to string in desired format:

```
$outputString = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

All this operations are considered basic and very simple. You should read PHP Documentation before asking something so basic here.

http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

Answer (score 0):

Using DateTime:

```
<?php 
$date = new DateTime( '19720505' );
echo $date->format( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' );
```

http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php